# ¿Cual es mi error en la sintaxis de List? - C#

Tags: c#

Quiero crear la siguiente estructura pero creo que tengo un problema en la sintaxis de list

```
List<ArrayList> vertices = new List<ArrayList> { { 'alfa',false},{ 'Beta',false}};
```

Por cierto que tuve problemas al probar hacer una matriz de esta manera tambien

```
string[,] vertices3 = new string[2,2] { {'alfa','nv' }, { 'alfa', 'nv' }};
```

Pero por alguna razon si puedo hacer la matriz con numeros

```
int[,] aristas2 = new int[2, 10] { {0,76000,0,20000,0,0,0,0,0,0 },
                                        { 76000,0,0,0,240000,0,0,0,360000,0 } };
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema de la matriz de string fueron las comillas simples me disculpo, tanto tiempo con base de datos me acostumbro a su sintaxis por ejemplo en ves de ser 'alfa' deberia haber sido "alfa" las comillas simples indicaban un solo caracter , lo habia olvidado... igual quiero saber como seria la sintaxis con List y arraylist por que no lo pude resolver, y al usar list y arraylist podria usar tipos de datos diferente en un arreglo como por ejemplo
{{"asd",false},{"asd",false}}

Answer (score 0):

Te falta el `new ArrayList` para cada elemento del `List`:

```
List<ArrayList> vertices = 
    new List<ArrayList>
    { 
        new ArrayList { "alfa", false },
        new ArrayList { "Beta", false }
    };
```

---

Aunque estoy seguro que lo que estás probando es puramente con fines académicos, te menciono que el uso de `ArrayList` ya no se favorece. Siempre es mejor usar `List<T>` en su lugar. En este caso, reemplazarías `ArrayList` por `List<object>`.

O mejor aun, usarías un tuple, que es mas adecuado para los datos que tienes.

Ejemplo usando `System.Tuple`:

```
List<Tuple<string, bool>> vertices = 
    new List<Tuple<string, bool>>
    {
        Tuple.Create("alfa", false),
        Tuple.Create("Beta", false)
    };
```

Si tienes C#7+ e incluyes la librerías para el nuevo `System.ValueTuple`:

```
List<(string, bool)> vertices = 
    new List<(string, bool)>
    {
        ("alfa", false),
        ("Beta", false)
    };
```